# Retornar infos do JSON no MYSQL no proprio SELECT

Tags: mysql, json

Eu tenho uma tabela no BD chamada "menu", com uma coluna chamada ESTRUTURA.
Ela era do tipo text, e nela contém um JSON com uma estrutura de menus referenciadas por IDs de outra tabela "categoria".

> Ex: [{"id": 1}, {"id": 3}, {"id": 4}, {"id": 131}, {"id": 125}, {"id":
>   5}]

Estes IDs acima são categorias cadastradas na tabela "categoria".
Porém, para retornar no PHP, tem sido bem custoso para a performance, fazer um loop, dentro desse loop fazer um `SELECT * FROM categoria WHERE id = 1, = 2`, e por aí vai...

Li que existe um novo tipo de coluna chamada JSON, que poderia referenciar informações na hora da consulta. Corrijam-me se estiver errado.

Mas é possível, por exemplo, fazer uma consulta desta tabela "menu", e nela, retornar as infos de cada ID deste JSON, em uma consulta apenas?

Exemplo do que gostaria (Não sei a sintaxe)

```
SELECT *, JSON_EXTRACT(menEstrutura, '$.*') as Data FROM sistema_menu WHERE menId = 1
```

Results:

```
ID  |  Title       |  Structure              |  Data
1   |  Menu Header | [{"id": 1}, {"id": 3}]  |  [{"1":{"id":1,"title":"Cat 01","active":"true"},"2":{"id":2,"title":"Cat 02","active":"true"}}]
```

Comment: Tem algumas pessoas usando a função JSON_CONTAINS para realizar o join. Não testei porém vale a pena dar uma olhada: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39818776/6432257

Comment: Obrigado @Paulo M. Não consegui adaptar ao meu modelo o exemplo, continuo na luta. No modelo de exemplo, os campos são retornados no JOIN mesmo, mas todos retornam como null, e não no formato JSON que gostaria

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer:

```
SELECT 
    catId, 
    catEstrutura 
FROM categoria 
having (SELECT 1 FROM sistema_menu where menId=1 and json_contains(menEstrutura, concat('{"id" : ', catId, '}')))>0
```

Ou seja, você procura as categorias cujo id (catId) está presente no campo 'id' de alguma das entradas do seu array JSON 'menEstrutura'.

O resultado vai vir em colunas:

```
catId | catEstrutura 
1     | {"id":1,"title":"Cat 01","active":"true"}
2     | {"id":2,"title":"Cat 02","active":"true"}
```